# mongoimport with CSV: --headerline does not convert first row to fields

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

When I try to import a .csv file into a (non-existent) MongoDB collection, the first line is not correctly converted to fields.

Instead, I get one new field with all the field names in it. In that field, all data is stored.

Example CSV:

```
product;type
Apple;Fruit
Pizza;Italian
Coffee;Drink
```

The command I use:

```
mongoimport -d db -c collection --type csv --headerline --file ./import.csv
```

The result I get for 1 row:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("56a89c5f3ea2a256f0da7acf"),
    "product;type": "Coffee;Drink"
}
```

Does anyone know whats wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CSV` stands for coma-separated values: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-csv

Not semicolon-separated ones. Preprocess your `import.csv` with something like

```
sed -import.bak "s/;/,/g" import.csv
```

Comment: 30 minutes after I posted the question I realised the same, glad you confirm it. Makes total sense. Misguided by Excel that exports CSV with a semicolon as a default.

Comment: @Kvs it is the whole command line. You need to validate resulting `import.csv`, then run mongoimport. `sed` is very basic, and doesn't take into account strings, escape sequences etc.